# What effects will stopping VS without saving cause the project in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I've got a project that I have in Team Foundation Server (TFS), on-premise. I've been trying, since yesterday, to check it into TFS. (I'm using TFVC, since I'm required to do so.) There's something wrong with the TFS server, as it is refusing to let me check in the changes. I was told by one of the TFS admins that I could remote to the server and restart it. Unfortunately, that is not true. I don't have the necessary privileges to remote to that server.

I'm wondering what would happen to the project in TFS, if I just close Visual Studio, while its stuck in the canceling check-in stage? For that matter, what will happen to the project in VS, while in this stage?

Comment: What do you mean by "refusing"? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Yes, I am getting an error. Unfortunately, I can't find the error now. And as I said, VS is stuck in trying to cancel the check-in. So, I can't even tell you what the error is without killing VS, in order to reproduce the check-in attempt.

Comment: And what might that error be? It's very difficult to help you without being provided specific information. Nothing bad will happen if you kill Visual Studio.

Comment: OK, I'll kill VS. Then will try to check it in again. If it fails to check it in, at least this time I'll have the error.

Comment: Killed VS. Tried to re-open the project in VS. I'll be able to, but the TFS server isn't available. "... defaultcollection is currently unavailable"

Comment: Thank you for your help, Daniel. For now, I'll leave the project alone until the Ops team fixes whatever's wrong with the TFS server.

Comment: Does this issue occur on the specific project? or specific collection? Have you checked other projects in another collection?

Answer (score 0):

Just as Daniel said "`Nothing bad will happen if you kill Visual Studio`".

Generally the pending changes would not be checked into tfs and they would be preserved in your local workspace after killing the VS. So nothing would happen to the existing project in TFS.

Based on your clarification: `Tried to re-open the project in VS. I'll be able to, but the TFS server isn't available. "... defaultcollection is currently unavailable"`

Seems the TFS Server is down, just ask the admins to check if there are any services were stopped. Or simply restart the TFS server.